# Problems creating a desktop entry for a shell script

Tags: scripts, icons

I did the following procedures to create a application launcher but it doesn't work.

1. create shell script named `shell.sh` with the following content:

   ```
   java -jar foo.jar
   ```
2. Added execution permission: `sudo chmod +x shell.sh`
3. Created .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/` with the content:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=foo
   Terminal=false
   Exec=/path/shell.sh
   Type=Application
   Icon=/path/icon.png
   Categories=Utility;
   ```

Then I have an application with icon, but it couldn't run, while double click shell.sh works. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some tips that can help you solve your problem:

1. Replace `Exec=/path/shell.sh` with `Exec=sh /path/shell.sh` or `Exec=bash /path/shell.sh`
2. Add execution permission to the .desktop file

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/share/application/<your_desktop_file>
   ```

Also unless you want that launcher to be available system-wide (ie: to all users) you can place the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`. As that folder is located in your home folder you don't need `sudo` to create/edit the file.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried but the problem remains. Maybe jar file couldn't be executed with desktop application launcher?

Comment: What happens if you replace Exec with `Exec="java -jar /full/path/to/foo.jar"`?

Comment: I used `Exec = java -jar /path/foo.jar` and it work. Thanks! So what's wrong with the shell script?

Comment: You should have some problem in the path used in `Exec`. I created a similar setup and if the .desktop and the .sh files are both executable it works. Check if you have spaces or some special characters in the path that should be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong with your entry, but I use the following app to create custom launchers. works in Unity too:

http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/Desktop+Entry+Editor?content=147818

Desktop Entry Editor is a GUI application for editing and creating application launchers for GNOME, KDE, XFCE, and any other desktop environment implementing the Desktop Entry Specification from freedesktop.org.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check that you either

1. use full paths in your shell file, e.g., in `java -jar foo.java` you need to replace `foo.java` with `/full/path/to/foo.java`
2. set the `Path` property of the desktop entry, which defines the working directory for your script, i.e., the script executes relative to the specified working directory.

If you follow the second option your desktop entry will look something like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=foo
Terminal=false
Exec=/full/path/to/shell.sh
Path=/full/path/to
Type=Application
Icon=/full/path/to/icon.png
Categories=Utility;
```

Comment: This did it for me, primarily you need the Path set